# Finding the maxima of each column of a matrix in CUDA

Tags: cuda

I have a 3D matrix (`dimx x dimy x N`) flattened into a 1D array in CUDA device.

I would like to find an array of maximum values for each column of each 2D matrix (`dimx x dimy` slice), hence resulting in 2D matrix of `dimy x N` maxima.

For example (row-major order)

```
N = 2, dimx = 2, dimy = 3 

A = {1, 5, 2, 
     4, 2, 4,

     4, 3, 2,
     1, 5, 3};
```

I want to get,

```
{4, 5, 4,  
 4, 5, 3}
```

as matrix of maxima, in this case.

What is the best (fastest) way using GPU to solve this problem with `N~300`, `dimx~3000`, `dimy~20` ?

Comment: This will be a completely memory bound problem, so the fastest way will be one where the reads are fully coalesced. This is a pretty broad question. Do you have a specific implementation detail you would like help with?

Comment: Don't know if your storage format is row-major or column-major, and that definitely affects the answer.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I like to compute approximated GMM(mixture of gaussian) for sequence of input vectors. Currently parameters are stored in row-major order, but I can change it in other way if it is better. I am implementing kernel function to find max in sub arrays using reduction, in which I have difficulty. If any draft version made, I will show you.

Comment: If you have matrix data stored in row-major order, a very fast and efficient kernel can be simply realized to find the max in each column.  The best storage format would not be to store the matrices sequentially, but to store mat1row1, mat2row1, mat3row1, mat1row2, mat2row2, mat3row2.  This would have the effect of multiplying your `dimy` and `N` variables together to create a single large row-major matrix of dimensions (`dimy*N`, `dimx`)  (Normally I think of x as the horizontal dimension, so your usage of `dimx` and `dimy` is confusing to me.)

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to solve the problem is using `cublasI<t>amax()`.

If you have **column-major** storage of each `MxN`, 2D matrix, you can use `cublasI<t>amax()` multiple times with `incx=1`, one time for each column of each 2D matrix.

If you have **row-major** storage, you can simply solve the problem by setting `incx` equal to the number of columns `N`.

Below you will find a simple example showing how you can do this for a single `MxN` 2D matrix for both the cases of column-major and row-major orderings. The extension to the 3D case is straigthforward if you think that a 3D matrix can be stored as subsequent 2D matrices. In other words, for the example below, you should change only the indexings and the involved offsets.

```
#include <thrust\device_vector.h>

#include <cublas_v2.h>

// Matrix A
// [1 5 3]
// [6 2 4]

void main(){

    const int M = 2;
    const int N = 3;

    thrust::host_vector<float> h_data(M*N);
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_data(M*N);

    // --- Column major ordering
    h_data[0] = 1.f; h_data[1] = 6.f;
    h_data[2] = 5.f; h_data[3] = 2.f;
    h_data[4] = 3.f; h_data[5] = 4.f;

    d_data = h_data;

    cublasHandle_t handle;
    cublasCreate(&handle);

    int result;

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {

        cublasIsamax(handle, M, (float*)thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_data.data())  + i*M, 1, &result);
        printf("%i %f\n",result,h_data[i*M+result-1]);

    }

    // --- Row major ordering
    h_data[0] = 1.f; h_data[1] = 5.f; h_data[2] = 3.f;
    h_data[3] = 6.f; h_data[4] = 2.f; h_data[5] = 4.f;

    d_data = h_data;

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {

        cublasIsamax(handle, M, (float*)thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_data.data())  + i, N, &result);
        printf("%i %f\n",result,h_data[i+(result-1)*N]);

    }

    getchar();

}
```

**EDIT**

It should be noticed that `M` in the code above corresponds to your `dimx` (column size), while `N` in the code above corresponds to your `dimy` (row size). In your question, you are assuming `dimx>>dimy`, so looping over `20` cycles should not be a big problem. Of course, the approach I have sketched below requires a further `for` loop over the number of 2D matrices (what you define as `N`). Please, notice that you can always merge the two `for` loops in a single loop. To improve the situation of the `for` loops, you can consider two possible improvements:

1. Use CUDA streams to try to fill as much as possible the GPU with work to do;
2. If you have a card with compute capability `>=3.5`, you can provide a further degree of parallelism to such an approach by exchanging the `for` loops with a CUDA kernel and launch the mentioned cuBLAS routine from within a kernel.

Comment: In my case, the size of N is much much bigger than M. So I am afraid looping over N would not utilize full capability of GPU.

Comment: @user3659509 I have edited my answer with possible improvements over the need of performing `for` loops.